# Starting websphere application server on linux (ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: websphere

I have installed a trial version of Websphere on linux VM (from *BASETRIAL.agent.installer.linux.gtk.x86_64.zip*). I want to start it using command line for testing. All I know is running `/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/bin/startServer.sh`, but it complains and throws error:

> WCMD0002E, startServer.sh requires a profile. No default profile
>   exists and a profile name was not specified ....

It gives same error for `wsadmin.sh` and `startNode.sh` too. I am not sure what server name and/or profile name are to be provided and where to find them. I searched for the same in `/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profileTemplates`, but could not figure out anything. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

You have installed the base package of the product but you also need to install the custom pakage. In simple words:

- Find the profile management tool and create the application server profile.  After profile will be created you will find the profile named as AppSrv01 at the following location: `/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01`.
- Then go to the following location `/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/bin` and give the command (`./startServer.sh server1`).It will start with the message server is ready for e-business.

Answer (score 2):

A new installation likely won't have a profile created. If you just want a profile with default server up and running, there are a few ways to do it:

1) Use PMT (Profile Management Tool) by using WAS_HOME/bin/ProfileManagement/pmt

2) Command line fully specified, for example:

```
WAS_HOME/bin/manageprofiles.sh -create -templatePath WAS_HOME/profileTemplates/default -profileName AppSrv01 -profilePath WAS_HOME/profiles/AppSrv01 -isDefault
```

This is the fully enumerated form showing which profile template is used and where it will be created

3) Command line with defaults, same result as above, for example:

```
WAS_HOME/bin/manageprofiles.sh -create -profileName AppSrv01
```

All three of which should make a standard server. Start it up using:

```
WAS_HOME/profiles/AppSrv01/bin/startServer.sh server1
```

Comment: Thanks ewoch and UK. Really appreciate. Works like a charm.